# Executing actionListener after the JS call returns true

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I have a code like:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{userLeaveBean.addAppliedLeave}" styleClass="apply_button" value="Create Leave" onclick="validateApplyLeave();">
    <f:attribute name="userId" value="#{employee.name}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Here I want the `actionListener` to get fired if the javascript validation returns true and if it returns false, the `actionListener` should not get fired. But in this case after the java script validation, even if the value returned is false, the `actionListener` fires. How can I manage it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got return statement inside your `validateApplyLeave` function and change

```
onclick="validateApplyLeave();"
```

into

```
onclick="return validateApplyLeave();"
```

---

Also, your can change

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{userLeaveBean.addAppliedLeave}" styleClass="apply_button" value="Create Leave" onclick="validateApplyLeave();">
    <f:attribute name="userId" value="#{employee.name}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

into

```
<p:commandButton action="#{userLeaveBean.addAppliedLeave(employee.name)}"
    styleClass="apply_button" value="Create Leave" 
    onclick="return validateApplyLeave();"/>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,
There is return statement in my js function and I have this also `return validateApplyLeave();`. But it does not work for me.

Comment: make sure you do `return false;` in your js function for example: `function validateApplyLeave(){if(someCondition) return true; return false;`